# If $f$ and $g$ are of class $C^{r}$ , so is the composite function $ g ∘ f $ , help with proof.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

First, here's the statement, and the proof for $r=1$:

[image]

So this is a proof by induction, but I need help with how the proof for $r=1$ follows by this logic, in the highlighted part, it says 'the composite function $Dg(f(\vec x))$ is continuous on A. But from my understanding, if that really is the case, isn't that the end of the proof for $r=1$? I think what I'm confused with here is the notation $Dg(f(\vec x))$, the author says this function is 'continuous on $A$', that means the domain here is $A$ (from what I understand), if the domain is $A$ then this really is the derivative of the composite function and it is continuous, so the composite function is $C^{1}$ and this should end the proof for $r=1$, but what if the notation $Dg(f(\vec x))$ meant that the domain is a set $B$ such that $f(A) \subset B$ and it is continuous on $B$ because $g$ is of class $C^{1}$ then we have to continue the proof to show that the composite function is of class $C^{1}$?

I hope I was clear, if my question wasn't clear enough please ask me to edit it, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $Dg(f(x))$ denotes the value at $x$ of the composition $Dg\circ f$.
It's a composition of continuous functions, hence continuous.

The proof for $r=1$, however, doesn't end here, because $D(g\circ f)(x) $ is the (matrix) product $(Dg\circ f)(x) \, \cdot (Df(x))$, so it goes on to prove this is also continuous.

Comment: So, in words: 'The derivative of $g$ at the point $f(\vec x)$ is the same as the composition of the derivative of $g$ and $f$ at the point $\vec x$?

Comment: No, the derivative of $g\circ f$ at $x$ is the *product* of the derivative of $g$ at $f(x)$ and the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: Yes, this is the chain rule that I understand, my problem is the first term in the product that is called '$Dg(f(\vec x))$', from what you just said in the comment, this term is the derivative of $g$ at $f(\vec x)$, but from your answer, you say '$Dg(f(x))$  denotes the value at $ \vec x$ of the composition $Dg∘f$'.



Is '$Dg(f(\vec x))$'  at the point $f(\vec x)$ the same as composing $Dg$ alone with $f$ and then evaluate that at the point $\vec x$? Or am I still wrong?

Comment: Yes, these are the same. $(u\circ f)(x)=u(f(x))$ for any function $u$. Apply it to $u=Dg=y\mapsto Dg(y)$.

Comment: Now I understand, the notation in the book is not so clear for me unfortunately, thank you regardless for your kind help.